# SQL : retrieving data by rank of variables

Tags: sql

I have a dataset like this

```
student_id, course_id, grade
1 , 1, 2
1,  2, 5
1,  3 ,5
2,  3, 5
2,  1, 2
3,  1, 1
3,  2, 4
```

I created a schema for this on sqlfiddle.com like below:

```
CREATE TABLE enrollments(
   STUDENT_ID INT   NOT NULL,
   COURSE_ID  INT   NOT NULL,
   GRADE      INT   NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO enrollments 
(STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID,GRADE) VALUES 
(1, 1, 2);

INSERT INTO enrollments 
(STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID,GRADE) VALUES 
(1, 2, 5);

INSERT INTO enrollments 
(STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID,GRADE) VALUES 
(1, 3, 5);

INSERT INTO enrollments 
(STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID,GRADE) VALUES 
(2, 3, 5);

INSERT INTO enrollments 
(STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID,GRADE) VALUES 
(2, 1, 2);

INSERT INTO enrollments 
(STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID,GRADE) VALUES 
(3, 1, 1);

INSERT INTO enrollments 
(STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID,GRADE) VALUES 
(3, 2, 4);

INSERT INTO enrollments 
(STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID,GRADE) VALUES 
(3, 3, 4);
```

Now here is what I want:

A query that returns the table with columns student_id, course_id, grade and which contains only the rows of the table corresponding to the highest grade each student was able to achieve across any of his/her courses. 
If a student achieves the same highest grade in multiple courses, then only display the row corresponding to the course with the lowest course_id. Sort the output by student_id.

So I wrote the following query:

```
select STUDENT_ID, COURSE_ID, GRADE 
from 

 ( 
   select STUDENT_ID, rank() over(PARTITION BY STUDENT_ID ORDER BY GRADE Desc) 
   as grade_rank, 
   rank() over(PARTITION BY STUDENT_ID ORDER BY COURSE_ID asc) as course_rank
  from enrollments
  ) as ss

  where grade_rank=1 and course_rank=1
```

I want to test if this is the right logic on sqlfiddle but it throws an error for the query

> ERROR: column "course_id" does not exist Position: 20

The schema has been successfully created there.

Is something wrong with this and how I can test if this is correct logic. If the logic is wrong, please highlight the error in code.

Thanks

Comment: i removed the extraneous database tags. Tag one dbms you are actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the columns in the inner query too, if you want to select them in the outer query. Additionally have to use one `RANK()` with an `ORDER BY` regarding both columns.

```
SELECT STUDENT_ID,
       COURSE_ID,
       GRADE 
       FROM (SELECT STUDENT_ID,
                    COURSE_ID,
                    GRADE,
                    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY STUDENT_ID
                                              ORDER BY GRADE DESC,
                                                       COURSE_ID ASC) R
                    FROM ENROLLMENTS) SS
       WHERE R = 1;
```

Comment: I added course_id and grade as I forgot to add that in inner query, but it return 0 count using my code. Why is that? Can't I get two ranks and then filter by those that are =1?

Comment: So urs is giving the correct answer. Why does mine give 0 rows?

Comment: @Baktaawar: Just run the inner query and you'll see why. E.g. the student with the ID 1, the rank by grade is 1 for courses 2 and 3, the rank by course ID is one for course 1. There are no two rows for that student where both ranks are 1. It's similar for the other students.

Comment: Yeah. U r right. So while taking it together it works because it sorts first by grade  and then by course_id within that grade?

Comment: @Baktaawar: Yes.